# TFS 2008 Source Control configuration

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs

Hope everyone here are doing great! Here is a situation where I need to know if there is a way to configure TFS source control in such a way that whenever I do a checkin I want to do a "Get Latest and build the local solution" first before I could actually do a checkin... as this would gaurantee me that every time I do a check in that the build will succeed.

However I am not sure if there is a way to automatically configure it in TFS?

Currently, I always do a "Get Latest" first, then I build the solution before I finally checkin the code provided the build succeeds.

Any suggestions or help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to wait for TFS 2010 and it's "Gated Checkin" Feature.

More Info [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160216063227/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/patcarna/archive/2009/06/29/an-introduction-to-gated-check-in.aspx), for example.

If you insist on doing this with TFS 2008 you could do it client side through a Visual Studio Add-In which either intercepts the checkin-command or offers a new "Safe Checkin" command, which then executes the get and build.

Comment: Thanks Toni, we are currently using TFS 2008 and looks like we will have to go with the Add-In you suggested.